# How to create a new list out of two lists in an efficient way

Tags: scala

Suppose I have some lists that look like the following.
(The lists are different in size)

```
Seq(
"xxx_code1_xxx",
"yyy_code2_yyy",
"zzz_code3_zzz",
"no-replacer",
...)


Seq(
CodeAndReplacer("_code1_", "-some-word-1-"), 
CodeAndReplacer("_code2_", "-some-word-2-"),
CodeAndReplacer("_code3_", "-some-word-3-"),
...)
```

What would be the best(scala) way to get the following output out of these lists?

```
Seq(
"xxx-some-word-1-xxx",
"yyy-some-word-2-yyy",
"zzz-some-word-3-zzz",
"no-replacer",
...)
```

Comment: Is the relationship of both sequences by position? Or one has to search for any / all replacements on the second list that apply for each element of the first? - PS: Using `Seq` is, usually, a "bad practice", because you can not reason about the complexity of any operation, you can not even be sure if the operation will finish since a `Seq` can a be an infinite lazy stream. One should always use a concrete collection type.

Comment: There is no relationship between the lists by position.

Comment: `_code\d+` -- it is legal pattern? Or may be, e.g., `xxx_c3_xxx`? In first case you can use array for `CodeAndReplacer`: `Array(null, "-some-word-1-", ...)`. It is more efficient (in terms of calculation's speed), but more complex. If not, you can use `Map[String, String]` or something for performance.

Comment: @d-_-b Ok, and for each element of the first list there is at most one replacement on the second list? Or there can be many? - Also, is the part to be replaced always the same? Like it follows any kind of pattern, or it can be any part of the string?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez ` for each element of the first list there is at most one replacement on the second list?` yes, each replacer(/code) appears in arbitrary positions in the first list once at most.

Comment: @d-_-b Then Leo's answer is the best alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using `find` with a `contains` check, followed by a `replace`:

```
case class CodeAndReplacer(code: String, word: String)

val l1 = Seq("xxx_code1_xxx", "yyy_code2_yyy", "zzz_code3_zzz", "no-replacer")
val l2 = Seq(CodeAndReplacer("_code1_", "-some-word-1-"), CodeAndReplacer("_code2_", "-some-word-2-"), CodeAndReplacer("_code3_", "-some-word-3-"))

l1.map( x =>
  l2.find(y => x.contains(y.code)) match {
    case Some(r) => x.replace(r.code, r.word)
    case None => x
  }
)
// res1: Seq[String] = List(xxx-some-word-1-xxx, yyy-some-word-2-yyy, zzz-some-word-3-zzz, no-replacer)
```

Answer (score 1):

Only brute-force comes to mind:

```
sources.map {
  case source => 
    replaces.foldLeft(source) {
      case (acc, CodeAndReplacer(sub, rep)) => acc.replaceAll(sub, rep)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use `replace` as `replaceAll` uses a regex.